# Is Poisson's/Laplace's equation rotationally invariant?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, poissons-equation

Is Poisson's equation rotationally invariant? Is Laplace's equation rotationally invariant? If so, how can I see this?

---

in reply to comments, my problem is that:

In my notes, when calculating the Green's function, the first step taken is to state that the problem is rotationally symmetric, so the Green's function $G(x⃗ ;x_ 0)=G(|x −\vec x_0|)$. Why is this valid?

Comment: The Laplace operator commutes with orthogonal transformations, if that's what you mean.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by rotationally invariant? Do you mean that functions which satisfy the equation take the same value even if their argument is rotated?

Comment: @TomOldfield. Well, to be honest, I don't really know what I mean. In my notes, when calculating the Green's function, the first step taken is to state that the problem is rotationally symmetric, so the Green's function $G(\vec x; \vec x_0) = G(|\vec x - \vec x_0|)$. Why is this valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An equation is said to be rotationally invariant if a rotated solution is again a solution. Laplace's equation is rotationally invariant; you can see this e.g. by expressing the [Laplacian in spherical coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator#Three_dimensions). Poisson's equation is generally not rotationally invariant because the right-hand side is generally not rotationally invariant. However, the Green's function is the solution of Poisson's equation when the right-hand side is a delta distribution, and since both the Laplacian and the delta distribution are rotationally invariant, so is the Green's function.